# Let Emacs align dot operators when indenting

Tags: java, c++, emacs, auto-indent

In Emacs C-like modes (C++, Java) I would like code to be indented as follows:

```
SomeClass someObject;
someObject.add( foo )
          .add( bar )
          .execute();
```

However, per default Emacs does this:

```
SomeClass someObject;
someObject.add( foo )
    .add( bar )
    .execute();
```

How do I have to adjust the indentation, which variables do I have to tweak?

Comment: I found a similar feature for the << operator. It seems the syntactic item stream-op is handled by the function c-lineup-streamop in c-mode auto-indent. But I haven't found anything for the dot-operator so far.

Comment: More information: C-c C-s shows me the syntactic info as: `Syntactic analysis: ((arglist-cont 17974))` or `Syntactic analysis: ((statement-cont 17768))`. So Emacs does not recognize this as a special syntactic situation. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use Complex align (highlight region and `C-u M-x align-regexp`)

When prompted:

```
REGEXP:  \(\.\)
GROUP:   -1
SPACING: 0
REPEAT:  n
```

Comment: Quite good, but that also takes comments into account. Leads to weird results... :)

Comment: Hm, I tried to build another regexp, which excludes the // comments (\([^/].*\)\(\.\)), but that also leads to strange results, since the align-regexp is not syntax sensitive.